# Parsing dates in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So my question is when I run this code for first time and it was giving me the results correctly i.e. in the format of 2013-01-23.

But when i tried running this code next time I was not getting the correct result (giving the output as 23/01/2013).

Why is it different the second time?

```
from pandas import *
fec1 = read_csv("/user_home/w_andalib_dvpy/sample_data/sample.csv")

def convert_date(val):
    d, m, y = val.split('/')
    return datetime(int(y),int(m),int(d))

# FECHA is the date column name in raw file. format: 23/01/2013
fec1.FECHA.map(convert_date)
fec1.FECHA
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample.csv?

Comment: NUMBER,CODE,FECHA,SECONDS,TID\n
85678367,52,1/4/2013,220242,0

Comment: `pd_to_datetime(fec1.FECHA, format="%d/%m/%Y")` or at once during the reading of the file: `pd.read_csv(..., parse_dates=['FECHA'], dayfirst=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing dates with pandas can be done at the time you read the csv by passing `parse_dates=['yourdatecolumn']` and `date_parser=convert_date` to the [`pandas.read_csv` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Doing it this way is a much faster operation than loading the data, **then** parsing the dates.

The reason you get different outputs when you do the same operation twice is probably due to that when you parse the dates, you take D/M/Y as input, but have Y/M/D as output. it basically flips the D and Y every time.